# DataTable / AjaxFallbackDefaultDataTable: How to configure the top toolbar?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, datatable, wicket

I am currently writing a web application with wicket, listing some domain dtos in a table view. I am using a `AjaxFallbackDefaultDataTable`, which is extending wicket's `DataTable`. I would like to display the "Showing 25 of 280" label always, not only if there is more than one page, which is the default behavior. I am adding an `AjaxFallbackDefaultDataTable` in a customized wrapping class like this:

#### List of input parameters

```
List<? extends IColumn<T, String>> iColumns,
ISortableDataProvider<T, String> dataProvider,
int rowsPerPage
```

#### Instantiation of DataTable

```
table = new AjaxFallbackDefaultDataTable<T, String>("table", iColumns, dataProvider, rowsPerPage);
```

#### Markup

```
<wicket:panel>
    <table wicket:id="table" class="table data-table">[table]</table> 
 </wicket:panel>
```

## What I got so far

Some answers to other issues with the `AjaxFallbackDefaultDataTable` suggested replacing headers, so I looked into this topic. As far as I could see, `AjaxFallbackDefaultDataTable` is adding a `AjaxNavigationToolbar` containing a `PagingNavigator`. You can always call `DataTable.getTopToolbars()` to get a `ToolbarsContainer`, but then I am stuck. How can I get further? Please help!

Comment: Hi,

have you already checked examples site? There is an example which i quite similar to your application:

http://examples8x.wicket.apache.org/wicket-examples/repeater/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.repeater.AjaxDataTablePage

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment! Where can I find the Java code for this DataTable example?

Comment: Hi, on the top-right of the page there's a 'Source code' link that shows the code for the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of replacing toolbars in `AjaxFallbackDefaultDataTable` i start with `DataTable` and add the toolbars i want.

In your case if you need the NavigatorToolbar, which shows the message "Showing 25 of 280", to be always visible you need to subclass it and set it to be always visible. Something like this:

```
public class AlwaysVisibleAjaxNavigationToolbar extends AjaxNavigationToolbar{

    public AlwaysVisibleAjaxNavigationToolbar (final DataTable<?, ?> table)
    {
        super(table);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onConfigure()
    {
        super.onConfigure();
        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @RobertNiestroj !
I'm going to accept it because the `AjaxFallbackDefaultDataTable` is preventing this sort of configuration and this is the best workaround.